# Serial port communication from ASP.NET application using WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

My requirement is as below:

My asp.net application has to connect to a serial port to get weights occasionally. But since its not possible to do this directly from ASP.net, I am using a WCF service.

How do I do this using WCF service? How do I get value back to the asp.net function? 
In serial port communication, the data is received in a separate thread.

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace SerialComm
{
    public class FileReadService : IReadSerialComm
    {

        public void ReadSerialComm(string[] _params)
        {
            SerialPort spComm = new SerialPort(_params[0], Convert.ToInt32(_params[1]), Parity.None, Convert.ToInt32(_params[3]), StopBits.One);
            spComm.RtsEnable = false;
            spComm.DtrEnable = false;
            spComm.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(spComm_DataReceived);
            spComm.Open();
            spComm.Write(_params[5]);
        }

        void spComm_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // data received event handler
        }     
    }  
}
```

Comment: so you are trying to get serial data from clients? or from server?

Comment: It is possible with asp.net to read the serial port of the server. It is quite the same in WCF. To read your clients serial port is a lot harder.

Comment: by "get weights occasionally" what do you mean... will it be only when the user presses a button on the web UI.... or, your WCF service will keep polling the current value and store them and when required the ASP.NET application will read first/last/all of those values (which are polled and stored by WCF service)?

Comment: I am trying to read data from the client machine which is connected to the serial port(My idea is to deploy a WCF service on the client machine). The users of the application(which is basically an intranet website) can click a button in one screen(weighing screen for instance) and they can get the weight from the client machine.

Comment: Are you looking to read the client machine directly from the server?  I'd probably approach it from javascript in the browser.  Have it make an ajax call to the service on localhost to get the data.  Build a buffer in the service to store the data, then just retrieve the buffer by calling it from javascript.

Comment: Hi Chuck, I am not quite experienced in javascript. could you please show a sample

Comment: I'd be a bit apprehensive about writing a WCF service which directly interacted with a serial port device, I'd probably write a simple windows service to manage the serial port, which writes values to a database, then have the WCF read those values from the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd approach this by having javascript in the browser calling the service on the local machine.  You'd probably want to have some preliminary calls to ensure the service is there and ready, with messages to the user if there's a problem.

jQuery makes ajax very easy.  You'll want to do some reading [jquery.com](http://jquery.com).  Grab the js library, and check out the ajax documentation.

Your code will look something like this (and this is completely untested)...

```
<script src="../Script/jquery-1.9.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
function readSerialBuffer() {
    $.ajax({
       url: "http://localhost:12345/readSerialBuffer",
       success: function(data) {
          $(".serialdata").val(data);
       }
    });
}

</script>

<asp:Textbox runat="server" id="txtSerialData" class="serialdata" />
<input type="button" onclick="readserialbuffer();" />
```

Something like that.  The idea is that the button click runs the ajax function to request the weight, and when that call succeeds, it loads the value returned into the textbox.  I haven't tried running this... it's just off the top of my head.